# Rails 3 find model attribute with foreign key in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, find, associations

I have two models, Reports(belongs to client) and Clients(has many reports). A Client has an attribute or column called "specialty". What I'm trying to do is to be able to call and display the Client.specialty attribute for that particular @client when inside the show page of a @client's Report. In my Report model I do have a "client_id" foreign key. I have no idea how to do this, I've gone about this far:

```
 @report.client_id
```

This obviously displays a number, but I don't know how to go any further, In my noob ways I want to do something like this:

```
@report.client_id.specialty
```

But that doesn't work obviously. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not the following?

```
@report.client.specialty
```

Comment: Lucapette - So funny, figured that out 2 minutes after posting the question. I'll accept as soon as it lets me, thanks!

Comment: Yep... sometimes you're so focused on something that you'll miss the simplest solution ;)